# Thresholding in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

How do I threshold an image to find the local maxima in a robust way?

I know I can just look at the data, visually guess at some appropriate *h* value, and do `imextendedmax(I, h)` where *h* is the threshold, but I'm looking for a more robust way to do it in [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB). I'm pretty new to MATLAB and coding so this is all foreign...

I'd need to do thresholding because of a noisy background (still somewhat noisy even after I filter it). `imregionalmax()` would therefore give way more local maximas than I need.

Answer (score 1):

Generate a histogram, find the max valued bin, then set your threshold at some fixed offset below this.

Or for a slightly more sophisticated approach, sum the histogram bin counts starting at the max value and work downwards until you have accumulated some fixed percentage of the total population, e.g. 0.1%, and set your threshold there.

Answer (score 1):

See whether Otsu's method will do the job for you.[Otsu's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_method)

It's implemented as part of the Image processing toolbox.["Matlab help for Otsu's Method"](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/graythresh.html)

```
level = graythresh(I)
```